# PHPUnit Mockup issue

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I have a mockup of a service class. 
It's defined like this in my `setUp` function

```
$this->myServiceMockup = $this->getMockBuilder(MyService::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['myMethod'])
            ->getMock();
```

In my test function i set an expectation for it like this.

```
$this->myServiceMockup->expects($this->once())
            ->method('myMethod')
            ->with($this->exactly(1), 'myName')
            ->willReturn($this->exactly(1));
```

So what this means is that when i should trigger the myMethod function only once and that it will return integer 1.

So method that I'm testing has that line of code.

```
$myIntValue = $this->myService->myMethod($number, $name);
```

After this line `$myIntValue` when i run the test should be 1 and test should continue, well that's my understanding on this.

But instead I get this error

> Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when
>   invoked 1 time(s) Parameter 0 for invocation
>
> My\Path\To\Class\MyService::myMethod(1, 'myName') does not match
>   expected value.
>
> 1 does not match expected type "object".

Doesn't make any sense since `myMethod` is expecting an integer and a string.

```
public function myMethod($number, $name)
{
    return $this->table->save($number, $name);
}
```

Can somebody explain to me what am I doing wrong here, because I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`exactly()`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers) is an invocation count matcher (like `once()` or `any()`) for using as argument of the `expects()` method.

Just replace the:

```
->with($this->exactly(1), 'myName')
```

to

```
->with(1, 'myName')
```

The `willReturn()` also accepts values "as is".

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using `$this->with` correctly.

```
$this->myServiceMockup
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('myMethod')
    ->with($this->equalTo(1), $this->stringContains('myName'))
    ->willReturn(1);
```